# How to print every single seconds (format timestamp) of a day using loop in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to print every single seconds of a day using loop in Oracle, such as:

i = 0  -> 00:00:00
...
i = 59 -> 00:00:59
...
i = 60 -> 00:01:00
(That's the thing I was confusing because when i = 60, it just be out to: 00:00:60)
...
i = 70 -> 00:01:10

Someone can help me pls? Thanks a lot.

Pls help me find a solution or code with example, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Or convert to an interval:

```
select numtodsinterval(level-1,'SECOND') as interval from dual connect by level <= 86400
;
+00 00:00:00.000000
+00 00:00:01.000000
+00 00:00:02.000000
+00 00:00:03.000000
+00 00:00:04.000000
+00 00:00:05.000000
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `to_date` function with `'sssss'` parameter as the following:

```
select to_char(to_date(rownum - 1,'sssss'),'hh24:mi:ss')
from dual
connect by rownum <= (24 * 60 * 60)
```

[see a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-MYcm6h6) for the first 100 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want 86,399 time references, but one way to do it is via a "rescursive common table expression" (recursive CTE):

```
WITH all_seconds (n) AS (
  SELECT 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM all_seconds WHERE n + 1 < 86400
)
SELECT
  LPAD(TRUNC(n / 3600), 2, '0') || ':' ||
  LPAD(TRUNC(MOD(n, 3600) / 60), 2, '0') || ':' ||
  LPAD(MOD(n, 60), 2, '0') AS time
FROM all_seconds
```

;

| TIME |
| --- |
| 00:00:00 |
| 00:00:01 |
| 00:00:02 |
| 00:00:03 |
| 00:00:04 |
| ... |
| 00:00:56 |
| 00:00:57 |
| 00:00:58 |
| 00:00:59 |
| 00:01:00 |
| 00:01:01 |
| 00:01:02 |
| 00:01:03 |